# How are Borg Ships constructed?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, borg

How would you say Borg ships are constructed in Star Trek? Are they built in shipyards like most ships or do they assimilate other ships that they come into contact with and just grow from there?

Comment: It's not canon so this is not an answer but: In the game "Star Trek Armada" you can play the Borg and there they use a fairly common shipyard to construct cubes. This is of course due to the game engine and, as I said, not canon, but I don't think there is a canon source on this except tiny hints and little clues in VOY "Endgame".

Comment: Through the collective hive mind, pouring resources together to form a new ship?  Just pure speculation, but based on how they *repair* their ships, which in other instances (e.g. Federation) is similar to the construction of a ship (consider a major repair/upgrade of a Federation ship to its being built)

Comment: I agree with the hive mind thing. That does seem quite likely

Answer (score 2):

The foundation of Borg technology is nanotechnology. They have also incorporated the technologies of all the species they have conquered or encountered, which includes material synthesis.

I would think that the correct term would be ship-worlds, as all they would need is a resource world or two to consume in the process of creating their ships, with the occasional import of elements that they can't synthesize.

Reference [Grey Goo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo) as the basis for that hypothesis.

Comment: Based on the repair of their ships, I would guess you are correct. I'm not sure if they show it in such a way during Voyager, but the idea of "resource planets" getting fed into grey goo sounds like something the collective would do.